# Transparent activity like dialog without previous activity under it

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to show transparent dialog-like activity when my app goes to background. But after it shows I can see the last running activity underlaying. Can I show only my transparent activity without finishing previous?

Answer (score 0):

I found solution. I have been used System alert instead Activity.